# 403 Forbidden error while making an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying to disaplay slider images dynamically by fetching all images names from slider_images folder and append it to  .

```
<script>
var dir = "images/slider_images";
var fileextension = ".jpg";
$.ajax({
url: dir,
type: "POST",
success: function (data) {
    $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {

        var url = this.href;
        var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
          //alert(filename);
        $(".slides").append($("<li><img src=" + dir +"/"+ filename + "></img></li>"));
    });
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can't request a folder via ajax

Comment: Can you try: `$(".slides").append($("<li><img src='" + dir +"/"+ filename + "' /></li>"));` ?

Comment: Folders cannot be acceded via ajax call. You can create service/api to return the list o image path (GET not POST), URL = http://yoursite/webapi/getimages

Comment: thank you very mush for giving me helpfull suggestions..

Comment: but same code work fine on localhost....!!! i uploaded as it is file to server.

Comment: $(".slides").append($("<li><img src='" + dir +"/"+ filename + "' /></li>"));  i tried this but still same error...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally i solve this issue by using json.**
first i create getimages.php file and read directory in that file and get all images names and store that name in array.

**getimages.php**

```
<?php
$filenameArray = array();
$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/images/slider_images/');
    while($file = readdir($handle)){
        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
            array_push($filenameArray, "images/slider_images/$file");
        }
    }

echo json_encode($filenameArray);
?>
```

call getimages.php from page where you want load images dynamically.

**index.php**

```
$.ajax({

        url: "getimages.php",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
            $.each(data, function(i,filename) {
                alert(filename);
                $('.slides').append('<li><img src="'+ filename +'" class="drop_shadow" alt="Slider Image 1" /></li>');
            });
        }
    });
```

**this is working perfectly for me. i you want please try this. this is very simple and easy way to load images from folder using ajax**