# How do I allow get requests - 403 forbidden error

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, http-status-code-403

I'm making an ajax request to my images directory.  This works well on localhost, but when I put it online I get a 403 (Forbidden) error.  How do I allow get requests?

```
    $.ajax({    
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
        var parser = new DOMParser(),
            doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html');
        var rows = doc.querySelector('table').querySelectorAll('tr');
        for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
            if (rows[i].children[2]) {
                var img = rows[i].children[2].children[0].getAttribute("href"); 
                if(img.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/) != null){
                    var html = '<li id="" style="background-image: url('+img+')"></li>';            
                    $('#nikoSlider ul').append(html)
                } else { console.log("This is not a valid image type: " + img) }
            }
        }
        nikoSlider();
        }
    });
```

Can I use something like `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` in a php file.

Comment: Please post the request headers and response headers that appear in the browser's dev tools when this request is made. The PHP script that handles the request would also be helpful. Finally the htaccess file that controls access to that PHP script could be the culprit (in particular any `RewriteRule` that has the `[F]` flag set

Comment: Not sure where that is http://primaryman.com/pare/summit

Comment: Is `http://primaryman.com/pare/assets/images/summit/slider/` the url returning 403 you're concerned about?

Comment: Yes, one of them, `http://primaryman.com/pare/assets/images/royce/slider/` also

Comment: `http://primaryman.com/pare/assets/images/  {{ differentname }} /slider/`

Comment: My guess is that you're using a 3rd party platform to serve your images. Along with the 403 response, the browser is receiving an actual response with info about the error. Enter the url directly in your address bar to see it. Maybe you forgot to upload the images themselves to the server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060464/403-forbidden-error-while-making-an-ajax-request helped me.  Is there a way to do this without PHP? Or is their a way to run PHP dynamically with each page load?

Comment: yep. checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `url` is of the form `http://primaryman.com/pare/assets/images/{{COLLECTION}}/slider/`, and it's a path to a directory.  According to one of your comments, you cannot access a directory using AJAX.  Here is the simplest way to solve the problem:

Create a middle-man PHP script that returns a json-encoded array of all the image paths you need. Then in your AJAX success callback, cycle through the images and append them to the DOM.  Since the `COLLECTION` part of the paths is variable, you need a way to always call this PHP script no matter what path is used. I suggest changing the `url` in your AJAX call to call the PHP script directly and feed it the collection you want. For example, if you're trying to access the `royce` or `summit` collections you would use

```
url: '/path/to/slider_images.php?collection=royce //<- or collection=summit
```

In your PHP script, you can find the originally requested url path with:

```
$path = "/pare/assets/images/$_GET[collection]/slider/"
```

You can then use that to get all image files in the matching directory (remember to only select files with image extensions), put them in an `$images` array and send them back to the browser with:

```
echo json_encode($images);
```

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060464/403-forbidden-error-while-making-an-ajax-request) (which you linked to earlier) has good code to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

@Patrick thanks for the advice, I found your answer helpful.  I ended up going with something like this which I'm sure isn't optimum but for this particular project works fine.  I borrowed heavily from [403 Forbidden error while making an ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060464/403-forbidden-error-while-making-an-ajax-request)

allow.php:

```
<?php

$filenameArray = array();
$summit = array(); 
$royce = array(); 
$soundview = array(); 
$merrit = array(); 
$hillcroft = array(); 


$all = array(); 


$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/assets/images/summit/slider/');
    while($file = readdir($handle)){
        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
        array_push($filenameArray, "assets/images/summit/slider/$file");
        array_push($summit, "assets/images/summit/slider/$file");

        }
    }
array_push($all, $summit);


$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/assets/images/royce/slider/');
    while($file = readdir($handle)){
        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
        array_push($filenameArray, "assets/images/royce/slider/$file");
        array_push($royce, "assets/images/royce/slider/$file");

        }
    }
array_push($all, $royce);

$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/assets/images/soundview/slider/');
    while($file = readdir($handle)){
        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
        array_push($filenameArray, "assets/images/soundview/slider/$file");
            array_push($soundview, "assets/images/soundview/slider/$file");

        }
    }
array_push($all, $soundview);

$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/assets/images/merrit-station/slider/');
    while($file = readdir($handle)){
        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
            array_push($filenameArray, "assets/images/merrit-station/slider/$file");
            array_push($merrit, "assets/images/merrit-station/slider/$file");

    }
    }
array_push($all, $merrit);

$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/assets/images/hillcroft-danbury/slider/');
    while($file = readdir($handle)){
        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
        array_push($filenameArray, "assets/images/hillcroft-danbury/slider/$file");
                array_push($hillcroft, "assets/images/hillcroft-danbury/slider/$file");

        }
    }
array_push($all, $hillcroft);

echo json_encode($all);


?>
```

And then my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){/* Loop thru images folder */

    var page = ['summit','royce','soundview','merrit-station','hillcroft-danburmer'].indexOf(window.location.href.split('/').pop())
    console.log(page); 


    var url = "allow.php";
    $.ajax({    
        url: url,
            dataType: "json",

        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data[page], function(i,filename) {
                console.log(filename);
        var img = filename; 
        var arr = img.split('/');
        console.log(arr[arr.length-3])

        if(img.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/) != null && arr[arr.length-3] == window.location.href.split('/').pop()){
            var html = '<li id="" style="background-image: url('+img+')"></li>';            
            $('#nikoSlider ul').append(html)
            console.log(html);
        } else { console.log("This is not a valid image type: " + img) }


        })


        nikoSlider();
        }
    });
 //rows[i].children[2] $(rows[i].children[2]).find('attr', 'href').context.textContent $(rows[i].children[2]).text() rows[i].children[2].querySelector('a')['href'] 
})
```